# Почему VS Community не может переименовать переменную

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Когда я пытаюсь переименовать символ я ввожу новое имя в окно "переименование", нажимаю ок, и иногда вместо удачного переименования пишет "не найдено ссылок в выбранной области", хотя вроде в качестве области я указывал "весь проект", а также пытался указывать более конкретно, однако ошибка остается. Сейчас я попытался просто объявить переменную, чтобы повторить проблему и действительно: VS не переименовывает даже объект, который использовался в исходнике только во время его объявления. Как это исправить? Такая ошибка была в версиях 2019 и 2022 на моем устройстве.